# merging two/or more bed file into one bed file

Tags: sequence-alignment, samtools, sequence-analysis, bedtools, macs2

I am trying to merge two bed files (more in future) to one. my bed files are something like : 
[image: result of macs pea calling].

I need to merge them in a way to have the shared chromosome location.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the easiest way to merge bed files is to use `bedtools merge`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert each of your Excel spreadsheets to tab-delimited text files ([how-to](https://www.howtogeek.com/79991/convert-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-a-tab-delimited-text-file/)).
2. [Install and run Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html), if using Windows. If you are using OS X, open up the Terminal app.
3. [Install the BEDOPS toolkit](https://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/installation.html) to get sorting and set operation tools (if you're not averse to using them).
4. Strip out the Microsoft line endings, strip the header, and sort each of the *N* files:

   ```
   $ tr -d '\r' < fileN.tsv | tail -n+2 - | sort-bed - > fileN.bed
   ```
5. Merge the files:

   ```
   $ bedops --merge file1.bed file2.bed ... fileN.bed > answer.bed
   ```

The file `answer.bed` will contain all merged regions from files `file1.bed` through `fileN.bed`. Merging will be done on intervals for each unique chromosome name.

Comment: Thanks that worked